# start 'forloop.counter' from different index or add something to the result

Tags: python, django

basically i want to count the iteration and end few tags after every 4th block
and 1st block is put manually so therefore the `forloop.counter` wont get the work done either I need to make the count start from 4 or just add 2 to the result `{% forloop.counter + 2%}` but add like this throws error `Unused '+2' at end of if expression` I am new to Django how do I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conditionally do something on every `nth` iteration of a `for` loop you can use the [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) template filter.

To start from the 2nd element you can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter to add `2` to the loop counter and then chain this with the `divisibleby` filter

```
<div class="container">
    {% for elm in elements %}
        {% if forloop.counter0|add:"2"|divisibleby:"4" %}
            </div>
            <div class="container">
        {% endif %}
        <p>{{ elm }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: i want my iteration count begin from 2 as my first block use to some extra features is inserted manually or maybe i can add and then divide to execute any further tasks

Comment: If you wish to begin from 2, you can use the `add` filter to add 2 to the counter. I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for? What do you mean by "my first block use to some extra features is inserted manually"?